# Typescript Module Resolution - Use local tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, module, monorepo

I have a monorepo with different packages. Each package has its own `tsconfig.json` and its own set of rules, for example, one package might be configured to use decorators, while another isn't.

The issue starts when I typecheck one package that depends on a package with different rules, it resolves the package with different rules, but typechecks it with the rules of the package that's importing it.

Is there any way to tell Typescript to use the local `tsconfig.json` of each package when typechecking resolved dependencies?

I've tried setting `moduleResolution` to `classic` to prevent any typechecking of resolved modules, but of course this doesn't work as typescript needs to resolve the dependencies to work.

Comment: `skipLibCheck` maybe?